# Cannot $select and $filter messages by the event fields

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server, microsoft-graph-calendar

I cannot $select and $filter messages by the event fields as described in this issue:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/2018

For example, when I'm getting the message the "location" field exists there:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxx/messages/xxx`

But when I'm getting the same message with select it shows an error:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxx/messages/xxx?$select=location`

The same is when I'm querying the messages:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxx/messages?$filter=meetingMessageType eq 'meetingRequest'`

This is the error:

```
    {
      "error": {
        "code": "RequestBroker--ParseUri",
        "message": "Could not find a property named 'location' on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Message'.",
        "innerError": {
          "date": "2020-07-24T08:28:02",
          "request-id": "f0e50e88-e69a-4ab3-bf78-4b3e933ad01f"
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The $select and $filter parameters supports only those **properties**, under **message resource type**, as mentioned in this link -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties. **Location** and **meetingMessageType** is not present in the list of supported properties under messages. Hence no value is filtered.

Workaround:

As **location** also falls under **properties** listed under **event resource type**, you can use the $select parameter for filtering event's location, by running the below query.

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events?$select=location

And instead of **meetingMessageType**, we can use the $select parameter with **responseStatus** property, under events to get the desired result. Below is the query for the same.

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events?$select=responseStatus

Please ref this link for properties listed under event resource type ->
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties

Thank you,
Rinki.